# PFSense NATing to a load balanced server

Tags: load-balancing, nat, pfsense

I apologize for not being able to post the network diagram here but as this is my first time asking a question here I am not allowed.

So here is the scenario:

We have a site that is build with a fancy front end and a work horse back end. The front end does things like indexing and rules processing where the back end does the work. The front end is able to handle all the load with out any issues. The backend needs multiple servers to handle the load.

Both servers handle HTTP requests to the end user and have public IP addresses.

My idea it to internally load balance the back end servers. This would allow the front end server to spread the load across the back end servers.

The second idea was to NAT the external address of the load balanced IP to an external address for the end users to be able to access.

So my questions are:

1) Can you load balance to the servers on the same subnet?
2) Can I NAT the external IP to the load balanced IP?

I understand that the load balancing feature is implemented using NAT. As such I am wondering if there are any conflicts as I would be NAT to a NATed address.

The site is currently running without load balancing and I am a bit worried about making these changes in the production environment.

Thanks in advance to the time you have taken to read this and for any suggestions that might come to mind.

Scotty

Comment: Post the network diagram elsewhere, include a URL to it, and then a higher-rep user can embed it in your question.

Comment: I think you're confusing things here - NAT and load balancing are two completely different technologies that don't really interact with one another.

Comment: Thanks for the Quick response. Here is a link to the image. http://i.imgur.com/mUYEsPD.png

In reference to relevance of NAT and load balancing. Here is a quote from the pFSense site "The relayd service implements server load balancing entirely in pf using NAT. " 

https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Inbound_Load_Balancing